# How to backup database using job to the server

Tags: sql-server

I've been searching for a while and cannot find anything about backup to the server using `SQL Server Agent`.

Is there a way to backup database to a server and not to a local disk.
I am not searching to backup from one server to another, yet I am searching to backup to existing server where my database is.

All I can find is this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Name] TO DISK = N'C:\some path goes here'
```

And sorry for such a newbie question but I am a new to the `SQL` and tnx for the effort.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server (Microsoft product) are very different, especially when it comes to backing up - which do you mean?

Comment: If `SQL Server` check my post: http://blog.devart.com/sql-server-typical-maintenance-plans-automated-database-backups.html

Comment: sry for not having mentioned. It is MSSQL

Comment: Do you have an SSH (Secure Shell) access ?

Comment: I have a direct access to the server over the SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [UNC Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) to specify the target server and share:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Name] TO DISK = N'\\server\share'
```

If you need help doing this via the Sql Agent, this link will walk you through the process:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/12/create-a-database-backup-job-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

Take care to do this properly. It's important to understand the difference between FULL and SIMPLE recovery modes, and what that means in terms of the need to backup transaction logs.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:
sudo tcsh

pico /etc/crontab
or
nano /etc/crontab

And add one of the following lines depending on your situation. This schedule the backup on 1am every day.

Remote Host Backup with linked PATH to mysqldump:
0 1 * * * mysqldump -h mysql.host.com -uusername -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql

Remote Host Backup:

```
0 1 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h mysql.host.com -uusername -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql
```

Local Host mysql Backup:

```
0 1 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql
```

(There is no space between the -p and password or -u and username - replace root with a correct database username.)

Comment: All I need is SQL Agent who can daily backup my entire database on the server, but don't know how to do it since all I find on the Internet are guidelines how to backup to the disk and not to the server.

Comment: You want to schedule DB backup using SQL Management Studio and store in your disk

Answer (score 0):

A great starting point is [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/). The `MaintenanceSolution.sql` script will create SQL Server Agent jobs for scheduling of database maintenance.

Regarding your specific question on scheduled backup through the agent to a remote backup path:

1. `Directory` parameter for the [DatabaseBackup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) stored procedure controls where backups are created.
2. When using [MaintenanceSolution.sql](https://ola.hallengren.com/scripts/MaintenanceSolution.sql) to create agent jobs and maintenance objects, set the `@BackupDirectory` variable to the remote server path (e.g. `\\FileServer\Backups`)
3. Under default agent job configuration, the agent service account requires access to the remote path

A more complete walkthrough is at the top of the [FAQ](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html).